# Create subsite shortlink

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to create a link that creates a new subsite with my custom template apllied?
This is not supposed to be a link to the page where you can create a new subsite, but a link that actually creates the subsite with my custom template. Just like a site would be created if I pressed the "create" button on the "New SharePoint Site" page.

Is this possible? Using javascript/jQuery maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in my project not using javascript or jquery but with the Server side code, you have to write a code to create a subsite using your subsite template under your site collection.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted the users to be able to create a new subsite with a ui button/link

Comment: you can write a code on a button click event server side , i am sorry i am not familiar how to do that in jquery